# Not all windows frames displayed in fvms' windows in vnc4server in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, window-manager, vnc

I have installed `vnc4server` on my Ubuntu server, to have it no screen 7 with GUI, but being able to run some windowed applications.

Also I installed `fvwm`.

Currently I have some windows displayed "bald" i.e. with no window titles to drag:

[image]

Why? How to fix?

My `xstartup` is follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `DecorateTransient` Style in your .fvwm/config (or FVWM Console):

```
Style * DecorateTransient
```

Comment: I didn't realize how old the post was before answering... oh well, leaving the response anyway.